# yii, how to select one column from model

Tags: yii, makefile

I have set up model with gii and I have  table call make and it has a few columns, there is one that is called make, how can I get all the data from column make back in the controller.

here is my action

```
  public function actionAutoCompleteMake()
    {


        $makeModel= Make::model()->load(fieldMake);


    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're new to Yii, you should check out [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) for Yii's Active Record.

```
public function actionAutoCompleteMake()
{
    $makeModels = Make::model()->findAll(array("select"=>"fieldMake", "order"=>"fieldMake DESC"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also with some condition :-

```
$criteria               = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select       = "fieldMake";
$criteria->condition    = " fieldName = fieldValue";

$results                = Make::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

May be It will help you also.

Comment: $criteria->select   not sees working, it still selects all columns